# List comes back as empty when retrieveing data from website ; Python

Tags: python, list, parsing, urllib3

I am trying to parse data from a website by inserting the data into a list, but the list comes back empty.

```
url =("http://www.releasechimps.org/resources/publication/whos-there-md-  anderson")
           http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('Get',url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.data,"html.parser")
#print(r.data)
loop = re.findall(r'<td>(.*?)</td>',str(r.data))
#print(str(loop))
newLoop = str(loop)
#print(newLoop)
for x in range(1229):
    if "\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t" in loop[x]:
        loop[x] = loop[x].replace("\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t","")
        list0_v2.append(str(loop[x]))
        print(loop[x])
print(str(list0_v2))
```

Comment: does this even run without any errors? because I don't see `list0_v2` being defined prior to `append`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Didn't really have anything else going on, so I made your data format into a nice list of dictionaries. There's a weird `<td height="26">` on monkey 111, so I had to change the regex slightly.

Hope this helps you, I did it cause I care about the monkeys man.

```
import html
import re
import urllib.request

list0_v2 = []
final_list = []

url = "http://www.releasechimps.org/resources/publication/whos-there-md-anderson"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
loop = re.findall(r'<td.*?>(.*?)</td>', str(data))

for item in loop:
    if "\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t" or "em>" in item:
        item = item.replace("\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t", "").replace("<em>", "")\
        .replace("</em>", "")
    if "&nbsp;" == item:
        continue
    list0_v2.append(item)

n = 1
while len(list0_v2) != 0:
    form = {"n":0, "name":"", "id":"", "gender":"", "birthdate":"", "notes":""}

    try:
        if list0_v2[5][-1] == '.':
            numb, name, ids, gender, birthdate, notes = list0_v2[0:6]
            form["notes"] = notes
            del(list0_v2[0:6])
        else:
            raise Exception('foo')
    except:
        numb, name, ids, gender, birthdate = list0_v2[0:5]
        del(list0_v2[0:5])

    form["n"] = int(numb)
    form["name"] = html.unescape(name)
    form["id"] = ids
    form["gender"] = gender
    form["birthdate"] = birthdate

    final_list.append(form)
    n += 1

for li in final_list:
    print("{:3} {:10} {:10} {:3} {:10} {}".format(li["n"], li["name"], li["id"],\
    li["gender"], li["birthdate"], li["notes"]))
```

Comment: Thanks,  I was in so much of a hurry to ask the question. I didn't make sure that it was clear. So, I looked at it and ran it with your changes  and I got the same thing. Then I realized that with your changes and my original code , I get a long blank line in my console. I copied it and pasted the blank line into my browser, and it had the content of list visible. Do you know why this is so? Again thank you.

Comment: @togun Not sure why that could have happened, check your terminal settings. Regardless, I rewrote your code so it takes the data into a nice format instead of one big list. Hope it helps you out, save the monkeys for me!

Comment: @togun whoops, note that there is html escapes in some of the names. Fixed that now, unescaped them and formatted the output.